# removing nested list elements with all zero entries

Tags: python-3.x, list

In a nested list (list of lists), how can I remove the elements that have all the entries as zero.

For instance: `values =`

```
[[1.1, 3.0], [2.5, 5.2], [4.7, 8.2], [69.2, 36.6], [0.7, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.4, 17.9], [14.7, 29.1], [6.8, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]
```

should change to

```
[[1.1, 3.0], [2.5, 5.2], [4.7, 8.2], [69.2, 36.6], [0.7, 0.0], [0.4, 17.9], [14.7, 29.1], [6.8, 0.0]]
```

Note: nested list could have n number of elements, not just 2.

Trying to do this to crop two other lists. something like:

```
for label, color, value in zip(labels, colors, values):
    if any(value) in values: #this check needs update
        new_labels.append(label)
        new_colors.append(color)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that `0.0` is falsey and filter using `any()`.

```
result = [sublist for sublist in arr if any(sublist)]
```

Comment: I was just about to post an answer using the more verbose `any(x != 0 for x in sublist)` but decided to upvote this one instead.

Comment: Thank you. Knew it was simple but working without coffee this morning. Appreciate it!